# Nodejs apis pending and response after 7s

Tags: node.js, api, response

I have a problem with my nodejs server.

Every codes work ok. But sometime, some apis were very slow (for every nodejs apis), **every slow api response after 7 seconds**.

It happened on production servers, I have never seen that in dev server.

I didn't use **next** in my codes, is that ok?

My servers (cluster) served socket (1k connections) and http (about 500rpm) **at the same port**. Is that ok?

My server codes (using socketio + express):

[image]

Exampling of a api:

[image]

Response in browser:

[image]

What's my problems?

Thanks!

Comment: In order to get some help, You'll have to show some code of those APIs.

Answer (score 0):

After changed nginx server configurations, I resolved my problem.

I have 2 server, both had the same backend codes, same options.

Socket is running on port 3333, http is running on port 3333.

Server 1:
127.0.0.1:3333 > https://example.com (http)
127.0.0.1:3333 > https://example.com (socket)

Server 2:
127.0.0.2:3333 > https://example.com (http)
127.0.0.2:3333 > https://example.com (socket)

Then I change it to:

Server 1:
127.0.0.1:3333 > https://example.com (http)

Server 2:
127.0.0.2:3333 > https://example.com (socket)

And everything work fine.